# Get Last 3 weeks before deadline for two certain date time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, week-number

I have two dates as start date and end date. I need to send a reminder 3weeks prior to end date /deadline I have set.

```
var start= DateTime.Now;
var end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 25);
var timeParts = StartEndDate.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

var eventstartDate = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day,
int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));


var eventEnDate = new DateTime(end .Year, end .Month, end .Day,
int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));

TimeSpan ts = eventEnDate - eventstartDate;

int totaldays = ts.Days;

int totalWeeks = totaldays / 7;

//Add 7 days for each loop until end date
for (DateTime ds= start; ds< eventEnDate; ds= ds.AddDays(7))
{
    //DO something so to get last 3 week prior to end date to set reminder
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: what if your start days fall after (before 21 days of end date)? is it the valid scenario?

i mean to say what will you do if  the difference between your start date and end date is less than 21 days?

Comment: @VinaySinha we will have some set of rules to have minimum 12 weeks long to create an event. and We will send reminder each week that starts 3 weeks prior to deadline

Comment: Okay, then @Pheonyx answer is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 weeks before your end date is 21days.

```
var endDateMinusThreeWeeks = end.AddDays(-21);
```